# How to extract strings separated by delimiters in progress openedge 4gl?

Tags: string, loops, progress-4gl, openedge

I have a string

```
v-edistring  = "STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY1'STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY2'STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY3'"
```

Apostrophe (') denotes termination of lines, each line is a segment. I have extracted each segment and assigned it to variable segment.

Now for each segment I need to loop to find the elements ( STS , 56 , 202 , DUE TO HOLIDAY1 ) etc in sequence.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE v-edistring  AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-cnt AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE segment AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

v-edistring = "STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY1'STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY2'STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY3'".

DO  v-cnt = 1 TO num-entries(v-edistring, "'") - 1  :

    ASSIGN segment = string(entry(v-cnt, v-edistring, "'")).

   MESSAGE segment
       VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.

  /* FOR EACH segment */
  /*DO:

  alert STS then alert 56 then 202 then due to holiday ( ie loop for elements )

  END. */
END.
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very elegant and I assumed your delimiters are consistent as you implied but here you go...

```
DEF VAR iCnt      AS INT  NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR ediString AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR segment   AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR iLoop     AS INT  NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR iLoop2     AS INT  NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR cSubString AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR cSubString2 AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR cValue      AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR iEntry      AS INT  NO-UNDO.
DEF TEMP-TABLE fred
  FIELD ParentID AS INT
  FIELD STRINGID AS INT
  FIELD ParseID  AS INT
  Field ParseValue    AS CHAR FORMAT "X(20)".
ediString = "STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY1'STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY2'STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY3'". 

FUNCTION getEntry RETURNS INT ():
  iEntry = iEntry + 1.
  RETURN iEntry.
END.

DO  iCnt = 1 TO num-entries(ediString, "'") - 1  :

    ASSIGN segment = string(entry(iCnt, ediString, "'"))
           iEntry = 0.
  REPEAT iLoop = 1 TO NUM-ENTRIES(segment,"+"):


    cSubString =  ENTRY(iLoop,segment,"+").

    IF cSubString MATCHES "*:*" THEN
    DO:

      REPEAT iLoop2 = 1 TO  NUM-ENTRIES(cSubString,":"):

        cSubString2 =  ENTRY(iLoop2,cSubString,":").

        if cSubString2 = "" THEN NEXT.
        CREATE fred.
        ASSIGN  
          fred.ParentID = iCnt
          fred.StringID = iLoop
          fred.ParseID  = getEntry()
          fred.parseValue = cSubString2.
          cSubString2 = "".

      END.
    END. 
    ELSE
    DO:
     IF cSubString <> "" THEN
     DO:
       CREATE fred.
        ASSIGN  
          fred.ParentID = iCnt
          fred.StringID = iLoop
          fred.ParseID  = getEntry()
          fred.ParseValue = cSubString.
     END.
    END.


  END. 
END.

for each fred:
    display fred.
END.
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution may not the best, but assuming the pattern that you showed, I think that can help you.

```
DEF TEMP-TABLE tt-data NO-UNDO
    FIELD sequence      AS INT
    FIELD string-1      AS CHAR FORMAT 'x(20)'
    FIELD string-2      AS CHAR FORMAT 'x(20)'
    FIELD string-3      AS CHAR FORMAT 'x(20)'
    FIELD string-4      AS CHAR FORMAT 'x(20)'
    INDEX ch-unique IS PRIMARY UNIQUE
        sequence.

DEF VAR i-seq           AS INT  NO-UNDO INIT 0.
DEF VAR c-aux           AS CHAR NO-UNDO EXTENT 4.
DEF VAR i-count         AS INT  NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR c-source        AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR c-data          AS CHAR NO-UNDO
    INIT "STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY1'STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY2'STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY3'".

DO i-count = 1 TO NUM-ENTRIES(c-data,"'"):

    ASSIGN c-source = ENTRY(i-count,c-data,"'").

    IF TRIM(c-source)               = '' OR
       NUM-ENTRIES(c-source,'+')   <> 4  THEN
        NEXT.

    ASSIGN c-aux[1] = ENTRY(1,c-source,'+')
           c-aux[2] = ENTRY(3,c-source,'+')
           c-aux[3] = ENTRY(1,ENTRY(4,c-source,'+'),':')
           c-aux[4] = ENTRY(4,ENTRY(4,c-source,'+'),':').

    CREATE tt-data.
    ASSIGN i-seq                = i-seq + 1
           tt-data.sequence     = i-seq
           tt-data.string-1     = c-aux[1]
           tt-data.string-2     = c-aux[2]  
           tt-data.string-3     = c-aux[3]  
           tt-data.string-4     = c-aux[4].

END.

FOR EACH tt-data 
    BY sequence:

    DISP tt-data WITH WIDTH 333 NO-ERROR.

END.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only the two delimiters, this code is a clean way to do the search.  It can be expanded to three or more delimiters, but I would probably structure the code differently.  (I would loop through a list of delimiters.  Let me know if you need code like that.)

One intent of this code is to minimize the number of string searches performed.  Instead of searching for both delimiters after each find, it is smart enough to only search for one.  I believe that this would make it performant without losing clarity -- but I haven't done benchmarking, and I could be wrong.  And as always, the optimal solution is going to depend upon the nature of your data.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE v-edistring  AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-cnt AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE segment AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE v-curpsn   AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-idxplus  AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-idxcolon AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v-element  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

v-edistring = "STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY1'STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY2'STS++56+202:::DUE TO HOLIDAY3'".

DO  v-cnt = 1 TO num-entries(v-edistring, "'") - 1  :

   ASSIGN segment = string(entry(v-cnt, v-edistring, "'")).

   MESSAGE "SEGMENT: " segment
       VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.


  /*
  ** Cleverness here....
  ** Find the first positions of each delimiter in the segment
  **
  ** Then:
  ** Clip out an element of the segment up through the next nearest delim.
  ** Recalculate the next postion of that delimiter
  **  ... and loop
  */
  v-curpsn = 1.
  v-idxplus  = INDEX( segment, "+", v-curpsn).
  v-idxcolon = INDEX( segment, ":", v-curpsn).

  DO WHILE TRUE:

    IF v-idxplus = 0 THEN DO:
      IF v-idxcolon = 0 THEN LEAVE.  /* no more delimiters */

      /* Otherwise, next delim is a colon */
      v-element = SUBSTRING( segment, v-curPsn, v-idxcolon - v-curPsn).
      v-curpsn = v-idxcolon + 1.
      /* No need to recalculate v-idxplus */
      v-idxcolon  = INDEX( segment, ":", v-curpsn).

    END.
    ELSE DO:  /* v-idxplus > 0 */
      IF v-idxcolon = 0 OR v-idxcolon > v-idxplus THEN DO:

        /* Either no colons, or next delim is a plus */
        v-element = SUBSTRING( segment, v-curPsn, v-idxplus - v-curPsn).
        v-curpsn = v-idxplus + 1.
        /* No need to recalculate v-idxcolon */
        v-idxplus  = INDEX( segment, "+", v-curpsn).

      END.
      ELSE DO: /* both > 0, but idxplus is next delim */

        v-element = SUBSTRING( segment, v-curPsn, v-idxcolon - v-curPsn).
        v-curpsn = v-idxcolon + 1.
        /* No need to recalculate v-idxplus */
        v-idxcolon  = INDEX( segment, ":", v-curpsn).

      END.
    END.


    /* 
    ** Display result.  Skip empty elements.  If you want to ignore
    ** pure white space (e.g. " "), then you can change this to
    **    IF v-element <> ""
    */
    IF LENGTH( v-element) > 0 THEN DO:
      MESSAGE v-element
          VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
    END.
  END.

  /*
  ** No more delimiters.  But there still might be one element left */
  IF v-curpsn < LENGTH( segment) THEN DO:
    v-element = SUBSTRING( segment, v-curPsn).
    MESSAGE v-element
      VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
  END.

END
```